# Not able to export query results to Bulk Csv

Tags: csv, workbench

I have a SOQL query that I am able to run in eclipse, developer console and the workbench (as a list).

Here is my query. The query is based on two standard objects - User and UserRole.

```
Select u.Name, u.Id, 
(Select Username, LastName, FirstName, Name, 
IsActive From Users) 
From UserRole u WHERE u.name like 'Inside%'
```

When I select the "Bulk Csv" option in the workbench, I get this error.

> Invalid Job: Unable to find object: users

How can I download the results to a csv file?

---

**The workaround I have is:**

1. Select the List Option.
2. Save the results page as an HTML page on my laptop.
3. Copy the contents of an HTML page to Excel.
4. Edit the excel spreadsheet and save.

Is there a better (*free*) alternative to do this?
[image: Error on Workbench]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a big fan of the [Salesforce Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh/support?hl=en-US) chrome extension. Once installed, it has an option of data export (helps you write SOQL lightning fast!) which you can use to export data as Excel/CSV/Json etc. Give it a try, it would save lot of time (copying results as HTML and HTML to excel must be painful!)

Comment: I have downloaded the extension, but I am afraid, I am not sure how it works. I was expecting to see something in my toolbar. I have restarted chrome twice after installing the extension, but nothing has happened yet.

Comment: Open up any list view or detail view of any record and on the top right where you usually see the sliding menu of Force.com (which has the options of View Fields, View Object, View Validation rules etc.) just below it you should see a similar icon with less opacity. When you hover your mouse over it, it would get high lighted and on click it would show you different menu like show field metadata, show all data, data export. The data export is the option that you should be checking out for now (dont miss the other features as well!) its really helpful.

Comment: I am trying to download the results for following query :
SELECT Name, (SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM Contacts) FROM Account

I clicked on export as CSV, after the completion of query I am not getting how to download the result ?

Answer (score 2):

If you run your own instance of Workbench, the synchronous CSV view is available. This uses the same query engine as the List view, so your query should work. This option is disabled in the public version for performance reasons. Installation instructions can be found here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Workbench#Installation

Comment: Just realized why this is broken. It's a bug in Workbench. The bulk client can't parse your query. Try using all caps FROM and I bet it will work; although, you might get a different error at that point saying that relationship queries are not supported with the Bulk API.

Comment: I am not really keen on installing my own instance of workbench. Thank you for confirming the bug for me. I will log a ticket with *salesforce support*.

Comment: If you don't want to run your own server, you can run into own Heroku with just a few clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have excel but I googled this link and if you copy the table from the developer console and paste it here: http://www.convertcsv.com/html-table-to-csv.htm it will convert it.